# Saving a numpy array to a csv yields a mismatch error

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, tweepy

I'm collecting a bunch of tweets from twitter and saving those into list before converting the list into a numpy array and trying to save it to a CSV file.

However when I try to do that, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1215, in savetxt
    fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
TypeError: a float is required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/keva161/Documents/Projects/Twitter Sentiment/main.py", line 66, in <module>
    main("Trump")
  File "/home/keva161/Documents/Projects/Twitter Sentiment/main.py", line 20, in main
    collect_tweets(api, query)
  File "/home/keva161/Documents/Projects/Twitter Sentiment/main.py", line 54, in collect_tweets
    save_to_csv(tweets_array)
  File "/home/keva161/Documents/Projects/Twitter Sentiment/main.py", line 62, in save_to_csv
    np.savetxt('test.csv', tweets_array)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1219, in savetxt
    % (str(X.dtype), format))
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('<U144') and format specifier ('%.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e')
```

Below is my code:

```
def collect_tweets(api, query):

    tweets_array = []

    public_tweets = api.search(q=query, count=10)

    print("Collecting tweets...")

    for tweet in public_tweets:

        userid = api.get_user(tweet.user.id)
        username = userid.screen_name

        location = tweet.user.location

        tweetText = tweet.text

        analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
        polarity = analysis.sentiment.polarity

        datestamp = tweet.created_at
        time = datestamp.strftime("%H:%M")
        year = datestamp.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")

        if (not tweet.retweeted) and ('RT @' not in tweet.text):
            retweet = "Yes"
        else:
            retweet = "No"

        tweets_array.append([username, location, tweetText, retweet, time, year, polarity])

    print("Done!")
    save_to_csv(tweets_array)

def save_to_csv(tweets_array):
    print('Saving to CSV')

    new_array = np.array(tweets_array)
    #headers = ['Username', 'Location', 'Tweet', 'Retweeted', 'Time', 'Year', 'Polarity']
    #np.savetxt("test_file.csv", new_array.flatten(), delimiter=",", fmt='%s')
    np.savetxt('test.csv', tweets_array)
```

Comment: Why are you converting a list of strings into a numpy array, just to save a csv? That doesn't make any sense. Use the `csv` module

Comment: But yeah, your error seems to be that you passed a format specifier "%.18e" which implies scientific notation, and `numpy` doesn't know what to do with that when your data is text.

Comment: `%.18e` is the default format.

Comment: @hpaulj right, there seems to be a commented out call to `savetext` specifying a `%s`, but again, if that's what you want *why not use `csv` module*

Answer (score 2):

Revisit the documentation for `np.savetxt`.  You can specify the format used for each array column or for the whole row with the `fmt` parameter.  The default value for this assumes you want to save an array of floats.

The default `fmt` is a generalized float format replicated by the number of columns in your array.  Evidently your array has seven columns:  '%.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e'.

But the error indicates that at least one of those columns, maybe the whole array contains strings, not numbers.  The dtype in the error '

`fmt='%s'` should let you write this array.  But check the result.  It may need some tweaking.

You commented out a line that used this format:

```
np.savetxt("test_file.csv", new_array.flatten(), delimiter=",", fmt='%s')
```

What was wrong with that?

`savetxt` is not a sophisticated function.  It just iterates on the array, and writes each 'row' to the file with:

```
for row in your_array:
    fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
```

where `format` is that long string of `%.18e` or something constructed from your `fmt` parameter.

`savetxt` makes most sense when saving a 2d numeric array. With an array of strings or a compound dtype (structured) it is harder to define a useful `format`.

Comment: Yeah, honestly to me `numpy` doesn't make any sense in this context, it's merely being used to take advantage of `numpy.savetext`, but that's not a good reason to use `numpy`, when the `csv` module would take care of this handily.

Comment: It is a full-fledged `csv` writing/reading module. It handles most typical use-cases easily and out-of-the-box, but you can specify all sorts of `csv` dialects and formatting options if you want to or need to. It also has `DictWriter` which can be handy in certain use-cases. For a list-of-lists with vanilla dialect, simply `writer.writerows(list_of_lists)` works! Obviously, if one's data is already in a `np.array` then `np.savetxt` is optimal, but converting to a numpy array, especially if the data is mostly text, just dosn'tmake sense. +1 for a good explanation of `np.savetxt` though.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html) module for this. So, assuming you are on Python 3, you want something like this:

```
import csv
headers = ['Username', 'Location', 'Tweet', 'Retweeted', 'Time', 'Year', 'Polarity']

def save_to_csv(tweets_list, headers, path="test.csv"):
    print('Saving to CSV')
    with open(path, 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        # write header
        writer.writerow(header)
        # write rest of data
        writer.writerows(tweets_list)
```

And don't even mess with `numpy`. Converting a list-of-lists into a string array to then just use it for `np.savetxt` is not a good use-case for `numpy`.